# Why does the following graph TikZ picture not compile?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I can't get the following to compile:

https://github.com/IMCG/graph-theory-algorithms-book/blob/master/image/introduction/bipartite-complete-bipartite-graphs.tex

I get

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, image externalization failed: the resulting image 
was EMPTY. I tried to externalize 'x', but it seems there is no such image in t
he document!?  
   You are currently using 'mode=convert with system call'. This problem can ha
ppen if the image (or one of the images preceeding it) was declared inside of a
 \label{} (i.e. in the .aux file): 'convert with system call' has no access to 
the main aux file.
   Possible solutions in this case:
   (a) Try using 'mode=list and make',
   (b) Issue the externalization command 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=
batchmode -jobname "x" "bipartite-complete-bipartite-graphs"' *manually* (also 
check the preceeding externalized images, perhaps the file name sequence is not
 correct).
   Repeat: the resulting image was EMPTY, your attention is required .

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.111 \end{document}
```

but clearly the code and the pictures are there. I am no tikz expert, but it also seems to be from a book, why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: Remove `\tikzexternalize{bipartite-complete-bipartite-graphs}`

Answer (score 2):

The line `\tikzexternalize{bipartite-complete-bipartite-graphs}` requires your current `\jobname` to be exactly `bipartite-complete-bipartite-graphs`. This is achieved either by saving the example as that name (plus the `.tex` extension), or running pdflatex with option `-jobname <desired jobname>`. See the pgfmanual ([pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), [web](https://tikz.dev/library-external#sec-52.4.5)), sec. 52.4.5 "*Details About The Process*" for more info.

Using `\tikzexternalize` without any argument is sufficient for compiling the example with tikz's externalization turned on. If what you want is compiling this example and this one only, not the whole book, then even the externalization is not necessary, as [@Simon Dispa suggested in comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642361/why-the-following-graph-tikz-picture-doesnt-compile#comment1601066_642361).